# CodeCop and .NET 4.6 - why won't it run?

Tags: c#, load-time-weaving, .net-4.6, method-interception

I have recently tried Code Cop 1.3.1 - a method interceptor.

However won't run when .NET Framework 4.6 is installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to this is to use the following **runtime** element set your app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <useLegacyJit enabled="1" />
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: with the release of v2.1 this step is no longer needed as RyuJIT is fully supported now :) http://sillycodevalley.net/announcing-ryujit-support-in-codecop-v2-1/